# Applicative functors in Underscore/Lo-Dash chaining - how to map inside a map?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I have a nested object like this:

```
var itemsWithQuantities = [
  {
    Identifier: 'SomethingWithQuantities1',
    Quantities: [
      { Name: 'Quantity 1', Amount: 4 },
      { Name: 'Quantity 2', Amount: 1 },
      { Name: 'Quantity 3', Amount: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    Identifier: 'SomethingWithQuantities2',
    Quantities: [
      { Name: 'Quantity 1', Amount: 3 },
      { Name: 'Quantity 2', Amount: 2 },
      { Name: 'Quantity 3', Amount: 5 }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Problem**: I want to fold all the 'Amount' objects together, to obtain `[7, 3, 8]`, see this as the horizontal sums of the `Amount` field. I want do this cleanly *using method chains*.

My existing solution **without method chaining** is like this:

```
var amountSumsNoChain = _.reduce(_.map(itemsWithQuantities, function(item) {
  return _.pluck(item.Quantities, 'Amount');
}), function (prevQ, nextQ) {
  return [
    prevQ[0] + nextQ[0],
    prevQ[1] + nextQ[1],
    prevQ[2] + nextQ[2]
  ];
}, [0, 0, 0]);
```

Thus far, the cleanest solution, using Lo-Dash's `_.partialRight`, I have obtained is:

```
var amountSumsChain = _.chain(itemsWithQuantities)
  .pluck('Quantities')
  .map(function(a){return _.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount')(a);}) 
  .reduce(function(p,c){return [p[0] + c[0], p[1] + c[1], p[2] + c[2]];}).value();
```

On the third line, with the `.map` call, is there any way to simplify that line more?

Why can't I use `.map(_.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount'))`? `_.partialRight` is supposed to return a function that expects one parameter for pluck, and as you can see, it works in the method chain above, but with an explicit closure function. Is there any way to make that even more concise?

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/qimekapu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: As far as I can tell, my problem lies with the nonexistant "mapMap" function that is found in Haskell. Putting a `_.map` inside the map call doesn't yield a chaining (i.e. comonadic) context, so the wouldn't work. The weird thing is, we can all see that `_.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount')` **does** return a one-parameter function and it works, but seemingly embedding that directly inside map does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can't I use `.map(_.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount'))`? `_.partialRight` is supposed to return a function that expects one parameter for `pluck`.

Unfortunately not exactly, `partialRight` is broken for that purpose. If we have a look at [the docs](http://lodash.com/docs#partialRight), they already indicate what happens:

> *partial arguments are appended to **those** provided to the new function*

A look in the source code confirms that the new function does not simply expect *one* parameter, but any number of parameter and just appends the partially given to them. And since `map` does call its callbacks with the item, the index and the collection, those happen to get passed to `pluck`:

```
_.map([[{Amount:3}[], _.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount'))
// is actually equivalent to
[ _.pluck([{Amount:3}], 0, [[{Amount:3}]], 'Amount') ]
// which will pluck the "0" property, not "Amount":
[ [ undefined ] ]
```

> it works only with an explicit closure function

[It's no closure actually since it doesn't have free variables.] Yes, the function works because you explicitly pass only one argument to the partially applied function. Actually you don't really need to partially apply it any more, but could just use

```
.map(function(a) { return _.pluck(a, 'Amount'); })
```

> Is there any way to make that even more concise?

To avoid the function expression, you might use [`createCallback`](http://lodash.com/docs#createCallback) to limit the argument count:

```
.map(_.createCallback(_.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount'), null, 1))
```

Not sure whether that is any better, though.

Comment: Ah. I had read that, but I misunderstood. I would have assumed it would have simple been a currying in reverse, sort of. As in, call it with 4 arguments, it fills the 4 arguments *from the end*, so `_.partialRight(_.pluck, 'Amount')` in my mind was equal to creating a curry of `_.pluck(?, 'Amount')`, which would then be a one-parameter function. This is obviously not the case!

But you are right, while the solution you offer is more concise, it is not really clear. I will use the simple and benign looking _pluck.

Comment: Yes, lodash should really have a `partialFirst` or so function. I had expected the same as you before I investigated because of your question :-)